# How do I make a smart playlist of my purchased music?

Tags: banshee, ubuntu-one

I buy from both 7digital and Amazon MP3 stores, how can I make a smart playlist of all my purchased songs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both 7digital and Amazon tag their songs in the comment field. Create a new smart playlist and match any of the following, and add `Amazon.com` and `7digital.com`.

[image]