# Where would I find the Purchased Music folder on my system?

Tags: 11.04, folder, ubuntu-one

Where would I find the Purchased Music folder on my system? I'm running Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for: `~/.ubuntuone/Purchased from Ubuntu One`

I make a smart playlist of all my purchased music so I have it handy and then I can manipulate it from the music player when I want to make copies, etc.:

- [How do I make a smart playlist of my purchased music?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34883/how-do-i-make-a-smart-playlist-of-my-purchased-music)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jorge in another answer, there is a filesystem location for purchased music if you really need to know it. However, I never need to; you can drag tracks directly out of Rhythmbox or Banshee onto another folder if you want. My music player is way better at dealing with music than the filer is.